# how to select a table name using a variable name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i select a table where table name has been stored in a variable.

```
$a='oop';
```

I want to refer the table as

```
select * from '$a';
```

But this shows error.

What must be the query used instead?

Comment: You only can do it if you store the query in a var and the use PREPARE and EXECUTE

Comment: @BerndBuffen nope, this is not true. Actually, you cannot use prepared statements to bind a table name to a variable, so you must use simple string concatenation to assemble such query. Obviously, the assembled query can be executed using a prepared statement, but there is not too much point doing so, unless you have other parameters in your query.

Comment: Just to clarify, `$a = 'oop'` is PHP and the SELECT is SQL which will be ran over PHP? This detail is important.

Comment: if you want to use a PHP var you must quote the tablename with BACKTICKS. you have use Ticks :select * from '$a';

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to enclose $a by single quotes in the query:

```
$a='oop';
$query="select * from $a";
//then execute the query
```

You cannot use prepared statements to bind a table name to a variable, so you must use simple string concatenation to assemble such query. Obviously, the assembled query can be executed using a prepared statement, but there is not too much point doing so, unless you have other parameters in your query. This means you have to be extra careful to escape any variables used as table names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$a='oop'; $query='select * from '.$a;
```

Comment: tanq gud job @Epodax

Answer (score -1):

try tihs :-)

```
SET @tab := 'user';

SELECT CONCAT ('select * from ',@tab,' LIMIT 10') INTO @SQL;

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE  stmt;
```

Comment: if you can use a SELECT in <?ühü...?> tags, you can also use this

Comment: Completely superfluous and waste of resources.